# Asynchronous Iframe not working

Tags: iframe, asynchronous

I have the following code to load iframe content after the main page loads

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    (function(d){
    var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
    doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // style the iframe with some CSS
    iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:200px;height:100px;left:0px;";

    doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
   'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'body\')[0].' + 
   'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
   '=\'http:\/\/google.com\'">');

   doc.close();

   })(document);
 </script>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, this code is not working as expected. Could anyone point out what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because this function is never called.
Give your function the name and call it from somewhere, for example body onLoad event

Comment: When i change google.com to `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com` is also not loaded, but the weird thing is that i still get a hit from my IP in the statistic in my cPanel

Comment: @aye where do u start your page? The reason could be cross domain access. If your page is on localhost, try to set the iframe to local page too

Comment: I tried changing it to the same domain, but it still did not work. In all cases, i see the iframe loaded, but the content inside the iframe was not displayed

Comment: @aye where do you run your function?

Comment: http://totgia.com/testiframe.html is the main page. http://totgia.com/time.html is inside the mainpage's iframe